# os.environ doesn't see some variables

Tags: python, environment-variables

I have one problem with os.environ. I set some variables in my bat file (for example):

```
set MYDIR=%CURDIR%
```

Then I use `set` command in command line of Windows to check it. Everything is fine, my variable was added. But!

Then I run my Python script and use `os.environ['MYDIR']` or `os.getenv('MYDIR')` but my envorinment variable doesn't show up!

Why does it happen?

My OS - Windows 7 x64, Python 2.5.4

Thanks.

Comment: How are you running the script?  If you use `set` on the command line, it only affects programs run from that particular command line instance.

Comment: So, first of all I created my bat file with set commands. Then I run it from command line. And next I run my Python script from PyCharm.

Comment: Are you running PyCharm from the command line where you run your batch file from?

Comment: No, it was ran by double click before creating bat file...

Comment: I understand, that Pycharm and bat file must be run in same process. But how can I do that? Run them from command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set works on session level. WinXP, use `SETX` from support tools http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18546 to permanently set env variable.

Or use `MyComputer>Properties>Advanced>Environment Variables` to set user- and system- level variables.

Never used PyCharm, but breef scan through docs shows that you might be able to set script-level environment variables within PyCharm, look here http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/run-debug-configuration-python.html